# Reactjs filter list in order by letter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of email addresses. I want to filter them when user type a email address. When user start to type a email address start with letter "A", the results list should show the email addresses only start with "A" letter. Not the email addresses the letter "A" from middle or last.

I'm using .filter method. When i type "A", it shows all "A" letter available email addresses. Not the first letter.

```
.filter(item => {
    return item.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.filterText.toLowerCase()) !== -1
})
```

**`item`** is an object and **`email`** is the value. **`filterText`** getting the text that user entered to filter.

Comment: [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways of doing it

using [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```
items.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().startsWith(props.filterText.toLowerCase()))
```

Or if it's only one letter you can just check the first index

```
items.filter(item => item[0] && item[0].toLowerCase() === "a")
```